# remove rows before specific values observed

Tags: r

I try to remove rows with `value == "no"` observed before at least one `"yes"` value in the column.

```r
DT <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3),
                value = c("no","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","no","no"))
```

Desired output:

```
 id value
   1   yes
   1   yes
   2   yes
   2   yes
   2   yes
   3   yes
   3   yes
   3   yes
   3    no
   3    no
```

Please help???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may do a group by `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
DT %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   filter(cumsum(value == 'yes') > 0) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 2
      id value
   <dbl> <chr>
 1     1 yes  
 2     1 yes  
 3     2 yes  
 4     2 yes  
 5     2 yes  
 6     3 yes  
 7     3 yes  
 8     3 yes  
 9     3 no   
10     3 no
```